# Image labeling: it's Monday again

Tags: python, image

This command line program applies defined labels along with Monday's date to a directory of images.

The script has to handle not being run on a Monday. Others are asking for the script so I cleaned it up as much as I could. I want to make it as friendly and as cross-platform as possible.

Labels should be applied just above where the white border region ends. I couldn't guarantee that the border region would always be white, nor how big the border region could be.

Any tips on making it shorter, more elegant, more user-friendly or more resilient would be helpful. I'm considering moving the conditions and text of the actual labels to a separate text file for more flexibility.

```
import os
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import argparse
import glob
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

path_sep = os.path.sep

def get_date_string(optionalArg):
    #return date of most recent Monday
    # or optional date param given by user.
    if optionalArg is not None:
        return optionalArg
    else:
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        if today.weekday() == 0:
            t = today
        else:
            t = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
        return t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

def significant_difference(v, previous_v):
    return abs(sum(v) - sum(previous_v)) > 200

def find_v_border(png):
    h = png.height
    png_ims = png.load()
    x = png.width/2
    last_v = png_ims[x,h-1]
    # walk up image from bottom, one pixel at a time.  when color changes, identify that as the place to write text:    
    for y in range(h-1,0,-1):
        v = png_ims[x,y]
        if significant_difference(v,last_v):
            return y    
        last_v = v

def find_left_border(png,bottom_border):
    png_ims = png.load()
    last_v = png_ims[1,bottom_border]
    for x in range(1,png.width/2):
        v = png_ims[x,bottom_border]
        # when big difference between v and last v, then return x
        if significant_difference(v,last_v):
            return x
        last_v = v


def draw_on_image(raw_img, new_img,date_text):
    global path_sep
    font_size = 16
    png = Image.open(raw_img)
    offset = font_size + 3
    bottom_border = find_v_border(png) - offset
    right_border = find_left_border(png,bottom_border) + 3
    fg="#000000"
    ttfpath = os.path.dirname(PIL.__file__)

    fnt = PIL.ImageFont.truetype(ttfpath + path_sep +'OpenSans-Bold.ttf',font_size)
    draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(png)
    draw.text((right_border,bottom_border), date_text,font=fnt, fill=fg)
    del draw
    png.save(new_img, "PNG",quality=100)

# accept arguments for image file directory and optional date string
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process given image.')
parser.add_argument('-p', help='path in which to find images to mark up...', required=True) 
parser.add_argument('--d', help='optional to add date you want displayed')
args = parser.parse_args()
image_path = args.p

#path references start from current directory
image_path = os.path.abspath(os.curdir) + path_sep + image_path

image_date = get_date_string(args.d)

    # read all the png files in image_path:

all_files = glob.glob(image_path + path_sep +'*.png')
for file_name in all_files:
    #parse file name to determine text ("Server, Desktop, or All")
    if "server" in str.lower(file_name):
        text = " Server Systems"
        new_file_name =  "labelled_server.png"
    elif "desktop" in str.lower(file_name):
        text = " Desktop Desktop"
        new_file_name = "labelled_Desktop.png"
    else:
        text = " All Systems"
        new_file_name = "labelled_all.png"

    img_text = image_date + text
    new_file_name = image_path + path_sep +new_file_name

    draw_on_image(os.path.join(image_path,file_name),new_file_name,img_text)

print("{0} files labelled with {1}".format(len(all_files),image_date))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Top level docstring**

It is good practice to start a file with a string delimited by triple quotes that explains the general purpose of your file.

Python treats it specially and displays it when queried for `help(your_module)` and saves it in the `__doc__` special variable.

Other people will get to know the general purpose of the code without reading it all.

A very basic start would be:

```
"""
This script adds time-stamps to images,
with particular regards to Mondays.
"""
```

**Confusing parameter name**

You write `def get_date_string(optionalArg):` where `optionalArg` is not actually optional... I am forced to provide it, an optional argument is one like `def foo(a=1):`

When names contrast the code I become very confused, also I do not think that kind of returning if not None is so useful, but I am not sure...

Actually you only call the function from:

```
image_date = get_date_string(args.d)
```

So you can remove the argument and the `None` check and call it like:

```
image_date = args.d or get_date_string()
```

Or, the equivalent:

```
image_date = args.d if args.d is not None else get_date_string()
```

**Reduce nesting**

```
else:
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    if today.weekday() == 0:
        t = today
    else:
        t = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
    return t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Becomes:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
if today.weekday() == 0:
    t = today
else:
    t = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
return t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Because you already returned, and when you `return` the function ends, so you can reduce nesting and make it clearer that the `None` check is just a precondition.

**Inline ternary**

I like ternaries because they are less powerful than conditionals, being less powerful means that they are easier to read and understand too:

```
if today.weekday() == 0:
    t = today
else:
    t = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
```

Becomes:

```
t = today if today.weekday() == 0 else today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
```

**Monday is equal to zero, but you should not care**

You write `today.weekday() == 0` to check if  weekday is Monday, but it is much more intuitive to read: `today.weekday() == MONDAY`

To allow this just add:

```
MONDAY = 0
```

at the top of your code, and you gained a lot of readability with a small effort.

**Avoid single letter names**

`t` tells me nothing about the purpose of this variable, try and think about a more descriptive name.

**`200` it was said...**

```
def significant_difference(v, previous_v):
    return abs(sum(v) - sum(previous_v)) > 200
```

Why `200`? This is very confusing, make a constant containing that value and give an explanatory name to it, because a random [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) `200` in the code just leaves me wondering...

**Similar ...**

The function `find_v_border` and `find_left_border` are similar, but sadly I cannot think of a way to abstract the similarity out... I just wanted to point this out as a possible further modularization possibility.

**Not needed `global`**

`global` is needed only when *modifying* global variables, so you may delete it from `draw_on_image`.

**Re-use**

Re-using singular functions is impossible now, as all the script will get executed if I `import` it, just putting the top-level code under a `if __name__ == "__main__":` will allow the re-use of single functions.

**Function for deciding name and content**

This block of code:

```
if "server" in str.lower(file_name):
    text = " Server Systems"
    new_file_name =  "labelled_server.png"
elif "desktop" in str.lower(file_name):
    text = " Desktop Desktop"
    new_file_name = "labelled_Desktop.png"
else:
    text = " All Systems"
    new_file_name = "labelled_all.png"
```

Only does one thing, so extracting it to a function looks like a good idea:

```
def find_text_and_new_name(file_name):
    if "server" in str.lower(file_name):
        return " Server Systems", "labelled_server.png"
    elif "desktop" in str.lower(file_name):
        return " Desktop Desktop", "labelled_Desktop.png"
    else:
        return " All Systems", "labelled_all.png"
```

Calling this from the top-level makes it more abstract, and you always want your top-level code to be as abstract as possible.

**Increase generality**

The `draw_on_image` function may easily be customized by the use of optional arguments, for example why should `font` always be 16? Making it an optional argument increases generality thus utility of your function.

**(minor) Avoid unnecessary assignment**

`os.path.sep` is never going to change, so you do not need to store it in another variable.

Comment: great stuff.  I implemented all of these suggestions and now have a shorter, more readable and more maintainable script.  Is there a way around importing both PIL and from PIL import Image etc... ?

Comment: @mcgyver5 you may do `from PIL import x, y, z ...` where x y and z are all the functions of the PIL module you used, but I do not suggest it. Also remember that (after waiting a day or two) improved code may be reposted for further improvents that the first review may have missed